# Проверка обязательных полей

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Подскажите как сдлеать валидацию на пустые строки (ввод обязательных полей) так, чтобы при запуске страницы это пустое поле не ругалось, на то, что оно пустое.

Т.е. чтобы стили связанные с ошибкой ввода проявлялись после взаимодействия с input или при отправке форму, а не сразу после того как загрузился компонент

Как пример, один из моих инпутов:

```
 <q-input
          :disable="noRequestsReceived"
          placeholder="Введите фамилию, имя и отчество"
          maxlength="256"
          class="full-width form-input"
          @keypress="checkNum($event)"
          style="max-width: 600px !important"
          v-model="data.name"
          :class="{'error-input':checkName}"
          @update:model-value="checkName"
        />
function checkNum (e: { keyCode: number; preventDefault: () => void }) {
  const char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
  if (/^[^0-9]+$/.test(char)) return true
  else e.preventDefault()
}
 const checkName = computed(() => {
  return !data.name.trim()
})
```

Comment: Вас интересует теория? Если практика, то приложите код, с которым вы не можете разобраться.

Comment: @SwaD мне бы и теорию и практика лишней не была бы :) Я добавил пример одного из поелй ввода и методов, которые вызываются при определенных событиях. По нажатию кнопки через регулярные выражения избавляюсь от ввода чисел

при обновлении значения модели проверяю на пустоту. Только также эта проверка срабатывает и при запуске компонента, соответсвенно поле горит красным и есть нотификация, но нужно ввести обязательные данные. Можно сделать так чтобы этот вопрос задавался после работы с полем ?

Comment: У вас фукнция срабатывает при каждом нажатии кнопки `@keypress="checkNum($event)"` Вам надо это убрать и перенести вызов на событие потери фокуса или на нажатие кнопки отправки формы

Comment: @SwaD а потеря фокуса - это какое событие ? blur ?